# Android Date pattern for locale

Tags: android, date, localization

I am building an app that will required the dates to be formatted to the locale.  I have it working using the below code, however Sweden use the date format yyyy-mm-dd but it is giving me dd.mm.yyyy. I have looked into localizedpattern but struggling to find a decent example of how this is implemented or if its any different from what I am already trying to do.

```
 public String formatDate(String dateToFormat){
   Date date=null;
   Configuration sysConfig = getResources().getConfiguration();
   Locale curLocale = sysConfig.locale;

   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   try {
       date = sdf.parse(dateToFormat);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
       //
   }

   DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,curLocale);

   return dateFormat.format(date);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The dateformat from the Netherlands is ("dd/MM/yyyy") with 4 yyyy, not 3 yyy.

Comment: Sorry my mistake meant to be Sweden for the locale, I will amend now.